# Add-on receives errors for accessing active sheet, and user info

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

My Add-on has been published and has been working for some time, and the published version available for about 3-4 weeks, available in the Add-on store for sheets. It has 8 users. School Announcements Easy works with a form and a sheet to automate the production of daily bulletins from form submissions.

One of the functions removes old submissions based on a date selected by the user. In June it stopped removing old data. Testing from the developer account shows it still works. I thought perhaps the date format was causing it to hang up, but it works regardless of date format, but not in my account at my school/workplace. Only in my developer account.

I looked in the API Console linked from `Resources -> Cloud Platform Project` in the code page. I have two errors:

> You do not have permission to perform that action. at unknown function

With the associated Stackdriver notification:

```
{
 insertId:  "1orur8efqvxg4e"  
 jsonPayload: {…}  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-06-01T14:54:57.277315484Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "2018-06-01T14:54:56.269Z"  
}
```

My add-on's code at bullMenu:18 is `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` This error shows up a lot!

The other error is more troubling to me:

> The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity.

With the associated Stackdriver notification:

```
{
 insertId:  "g3dkpzf2htk4x"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/project-id-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-06-01T14:55:50.288011162Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity:  "WARNING"  
 textPayload:  "The script does not have permission to get the active user's identity."  
 timestamp:  "2018-06-01T14:55:49.286Z"  
}
```

To my knowledge I did not write any code that requests the user's identity.

Any clues on how to track these down would help. It seems they may be connected in some way, and only started on June 1. Prior to that, it worked great.

I did make an attempt to install FireBase and added code to the head of one of the pages as follows:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

It seems likely that this is the culprit, that I may be using Firebase improperly or have the wrong version. I'm adapting to writing add-ons, but FireBase is totally new to me, and seems essential.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been getting the console warning about an invoked custom function attempting to access the user's identity as well, in any workbook that has an `onOpen` simple trigger, whenever the workbook is opened, even when the only thing that script does is initialize a menu.

Comment: interesting, so it may not be my own doing for a change...

Comment: I'll have to test my other add-on from a separate account and see if it is behaving similarly.

Comment: There is an associated Issue in the Apps Script tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109710390

Comment: Other people have reported this:  [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/+AmitAgarwal/posts/A1oxeKmaDG2) And also [Another](https://plus.google.com/107059691808080643296/posts/TMc5ZYyMWsS)

Comment: I've narrowed it down to using any simple trigger. When Google populates the event object for that function, it is now sending a warning for attempting to access `Session.getActiveUser()`, even though you have no way to tell it to not bother with that. (Even if you don't bind the argument, it is still there in the implicit function arguments.)